# Как вручную создать вложенную форму в Symfony 4 и заполнить её массивом

Tags: form, symfony4

Есть сущность myEntity со свойством records типа json, который после десериализации выглядит так:

```
class myEntity
{
    public function getRecords()
    {
        return [
            ['param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2'],
            ['param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Хочу создать форму, которая будет заполняться этими десериализованными значениями, и оставлять еще одну "строку" для новых значений:

```
MAIN FORM
    -> Record #1
        -> Param 1
        -> Param 2
    -> Record #2
        -> Param 1
        -> Param 2
    -> New Record <- пустая строка для новых значений
        -> Param 1
        -> Param 2
```

Создаю новую форму в контроллере:

```
$this->container->get('form.factory')->create(myMainForm::class, $myEntity);
```

В основной форме создаю вложенную `records`:

```
class myMainFormType extends EasyAdminFormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('records', myRecordsType::class);
    }
}
```

А вот тут у меня проблемы, я не знаю как мне перебрать все существующие значения массива (и добавить еще один дополнительно), $builder->getData() пустой:

```
class myRecordsType extends EasyAdminFormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // TODO buildForm(), something like:
        // foreach (... as ...)
        // {
        //      $builder->add('record', myRecordType::class);
        // }
    }
}
```

И в конце-концов будут создаваться сами текстовые поля, тут как раз всё ясно:

```
class myRecordType extends EasyAdminFormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('param1', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('param2', TextType::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getData` - это метод класса `FormEvent`. Предпологаю, что нужно навесить событие, 
и в нем вызывать `getData`.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
   ...
   $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA /*POST_SUBMIT ...*/, function (FormEvent $event) {
          $data = $event->getData();
          //и тут уже перебор  
   });
}
```

События которые есть в [Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html).

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря помощи @kostiantyn-okhotnyk получилось так:

```
class myRecordsType extends EasyAdminFormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            foreach ($event->getData() as $i => $d) {
                $form->add($i, MyRecordType::class);
                $form->get($i)->setData($d);
            }
            $i = isset($i) ? $i++ : 0;
            $form->add($i, MyRecordType::class);
        });
    }
}
```